# Change the 'always' word when editing a post from italics to bold

Tags: feature-request, edits, design, editing-help

This has bugged me for a while now, and I thought I would create a post about it. This is what you see in the right hand corner when editing a user's post:

[image]

To me, the word *always*, gives a sense of sarcasm and not of importance due to being in italics.

I feel that if the style of the word *always* (italics) was changed to **always** (bold), it would stand out more and show that it must be followed and isn't something to take lightly - or even just remove the italics.

Comment: "To me, the word always, gives a sense of sarcasm and not of importance due to being in italics" -- I don't get this impression at all. In this context, italics is just a form of emphasising which is softer and less obtrusive than bold, which seems appropriate there.

Answer (score 10):

On the Internet, italics denote *emphasis*, not sarcasm. The [<em> HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em#<i>_vs._<em>) (emphasis) produces the same results as the <i> element (italic).

By the way, **bold** elements also indicate emphasis, even more than italics. In the new HTML standard, its functional replacement is [<strong>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong#Bold_vs._Strong). The author of that page might have felt that 'emphasis level 2' would be too much emphasis here.